# Changing image links in text [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I want to replace the image links in the text with the following, but it doesn't. I'm sure everything is correct but I don't know what the problem is. Can you help me with this issue?

> {#img='image_name.jpg', alt=''}

PHP code:

```
$text = "Hello <img src='https://example.com/image1.jpg'> , <img src='example.com/image2.jpg'> and now you :)";
    $re = '/<img.*?src=[\'"]([^"\'])[\'"]>/'; 
    preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    foreach ($matches as $val) {
        $str = preg_replace('/<img.*?src=[\'"](' . $val[1] . ')[\'"]>/', "{#img='" . $val[1] . "', alt=''}", $text);
    }
    var_dump($text);
```

Result:

```
Hello <img src='https://example.com/image1.jpg'> , <img src='https://example.com/image2.jpg'> and now you :)
```

Comment: Not an explanation of why your attempt doesn't work, but using `preg_replace` with the `/g` modifier and `\1` in the replacement string would be simpler than using `preg_match_all` and a loop.

Comment: You're putting the replaced text in `$str` and then you dump the original `$text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there is no match is because in the pattern `<img.*?src=[\'"]([^"\'])[\'"]>` you have to repeat the character class `([^"\']*)` because now you are matching exactly 1 occurrence.

Then in the foreach loop the replaced string is in variable `$str` because
`$text` is not touched at all, it is only passed to preg_match_all.

But you don't need to match first, and then do a loop calling preg_replace separately.

You might use for example only preg_replace, and use the capture group 2 value that contains the url for the replacement.

```
$text = "Hello <img src='https://example.com/image1.jpg'> , <img src='example.com/image2.jpg'> and now you :)";
$str = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*src=([\'"])(.*?)\1>/', "{#img='$2', alt=''}", $text);

echo $str;
```

Output

```
Hello {#img='https://example.com/image1.jpg', alt=''} , {#img='example.com/image2.jpg', alt=''} and now you :)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/45kowV/1) for the matches on regex101 and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/0Vnv9) on 3v4l.org.

Comment: I can't believe the `$str` error. I think I need a cold drink:). I have reviewed your code and it has been both helpful and instructive for me. Thank you.